# Docker Container exits upon running with "sh -c"

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to run a webserver (right now still locally) out of a docker container. I am currently going step by step to understand the different parts.

---

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
ENV environment development

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN cd /app/client && yarn && yarn build
RUN cd /app/server && yarn 

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["sh", "-c","NODE_ENV=${environment}", "node", "server/server.js"]
```

*Explanation:*
I have the `"sh", "-c"` part in the CMD command due to the fact that without it I was getting this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"NODE_ENV=${environment}\": executable file not found in $PATH":
>   unknown.

---

**Building the container:**

Building the container works just fine with:

```
docker build -t auth_example .
```

It takes a little while since the build context is (even after excluding all the node_modules) roughly 37MB, but that's okay.

---

**Running the container:**

Running the container and the app inside works like a charm if I do:

```
MyZSH: docker run -it -p 5000:5000 auth_example /bin/sh
/app # NODE_ENV=development node server/server.js
```

However, when running the container via the CMD command like this:

```
MyZSH: docker run -p 5000:5000 auth_example
```

Nothing happens, no errors, no nothing. The logs are empty and a `docker ps -a` reveals that the container was exited right upon start. I did some googling and tried different combinations of `-t -i -d` but that didn't solve it either.

Can anybody shed some light on this or point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing three arguments to `sh -c` whereas you'd usually pass one (`sh -c "... ... ..."`).

It's likely you don't need the `sh -c` invocation at all; use `/usr/bin/env` to alias that environment variable instead (or just directly pass in `NODE_ENV` instead of `environment`):

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
ENV environment development

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN cd /app/client && yarn && yarn build
RUN cd /app/server && yarn 

EXPOSE 5000
CMD /usr/bin/env NODE_ENV=${environment} node server/server.js
```

Comment: looks very promising. Could you explain why it seemed like it worked even though I was passing multiple arguments? to "sh -c" and what your proposed solution does differently?

Comment: The thing is `sh -c` expects _one_ argument after it, the full command string, but you're passing it three, and it only reads the first. That is, it assigns that local variable `NODE_ENV` and then quits directly after.

Comment: You can also directly set `ENV NODE_ENV=${environment}`, or even just consistently use the `NODE_ENV` name throughout the Dockerfile (you'll need a multi-stage build if `yarn build` has tools like `tsc` or Webpack).

Comment: @AKX ohh another question, could you explain why /usr/bin/env works?

Comment: Two things at play - you're now using the non-array form of RUN so the arguments get sliced up correctly, and `/usr/bin/env` parses the `FOO=bar` arguments out and sets the envvars.